# ember js 'undefined' in url

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

This is my menu bar code in html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="links">
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">     
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li>{{#link-to "myleaves" 1255 action="myleavesinfolist"}}My Leave{{/link-to}}</li>
 <li>{{#link-to "approvalrequests" 1255 action="appreqlist"}}Approval Requests{{/link-to}}</li>
<p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" {{action "logout"}}>Logout</button></p>
<p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><font color="white" size=4>Welcome {{model.userName}}</font></p>
</ul>
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

Here is my ember js code

```
App.Router.map(function () {
this.resource("signin", {path: "/"});
this.resource("links", {path: "/:id"},
     function () {this.resource("myleaves",path: "/myleaves/:id"});
     this.resource("approvalrequests", {path: "/appreq/:id"});
  });
});
```

am bringing data by below code

```
App.LinksController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
actions: {
myleavesinfolist: function () {
  rdata = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myleaves",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
  }).responseJSON;
  this.transitionToRoute("myleaves", rdata);
} //myleavesinfolist
,
appreqlist: function () {
  rdata = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/aprreq",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
  }).responseJSON;
  final = filterData(rdata);
  console.log(final);
  this.transitionToRoute("approvalrequests", final);
} //appreqlist

} //actions
}); //controller
```

but when i click on menu link "myleaves " or "approval requests"

my url is like

```
http://localhost:8888/Leave.html#/undefined/myleaves/undefined
```

i dont knw why this undefined is coming..

PLease help

am a newbie

Answer (score 0):

`link-to` expects a model object as its second argument, rather than an id.

So you’ll likely want to load the models for `myleaves` and `approvalrequests` earlier on—perhaps in your ApplicationRoute:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      myLeaves: this.store.find('leaves'), // or however you fetch model data
      approvalRequests: this.store.find('approval-request') // ditto
    });
  }
});
```

And the template becomes:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="links">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">     
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li>{{#link-to "myleaves" myLeaves action="myleavesinfolist"}}My Leaves{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "approvalrequests" approvalRequests action="appreqlist"}}Approval Requests{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" {{action "logout"}}>Logout</button></p>
    <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><font color="white" size=4>Welcome {{model.userName}}</font></p>
  </div>
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

## EDIT

Based on your model code—and the fact that your requests don’t actually depend on the ID—I’d suggest the following:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('signin', { path: '/' });
  this.resource('links', { path: '/links' }, function() {
    this.resource('my-leaves', { path: '/myleaves' });
    this.resource('approval-requests', { path: '/appreq' });
  });
});

function getJSONByPost(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}

App.MyLeavesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return getJSONByPost('/myleaves');
  }
});

App.ApprovalRequestsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return getJSONByPost('/aprreq');
  }
});
```

Your template becomes:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="links">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li>{{#link-to "my-leaves"}}My Leaves{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "approval-requests"}}Approval Requests{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" {{action "logout"}}>Logout</button></p>
    <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><font color="white" size=4>Welcome {{userName}}</font></p>
  </div>

  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

This is a bit of a departure from what you currently have. It’s hard to know the full structure and flow of your app without speaking directly. Nevertheless, I hope it’s of some use.

Comment: i have added code for bringing model data.can you please modify your answer accordingly.....Thank You

Comment: Answer modified accordingly.

Comment: but when i added your code am getting script error saying  "Error: More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: links.index"

Comment: Where are you linking to index? Or rather: where are you linking to "links"?

Comment: Iam not linking to "links" anywhere but am just trasitioning to links template as the user log's in am using, "this.transitionToRoute("links", rdata)"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52375/discussion-between-kranthi-sama-and-jamie-white)